# Working with cx_Freeze - how to include all necessary files in .exe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I want to make a self-contained .exe file.

I have managed to use cx_Freeze to build one that works on my machine, but it is throwing an error about needing the .dlls when I sent it to someone. I read a few of the similar questions, which is how I ended up including packages in the build options.

I suspect that once I get past this particular problem, I will end up needing to include other stuff in the .exe....any help getting around that pitfall is appreciated! The end user needs to be able to only use the .exe and not have to install other files.

[image: The included files in the exe directory]

Here is my current setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

build_options = {"includes" : [ "re", "atexit"], "packages": ["PyQt4.QtCore", "PyQt4.QtGui"]}

setup(  name = "Hex Script Combination",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Contact (info) with questions",
        options = {"build_exe" : build_options},
        executables = [Executable("Project.py", base=base)])
```

ETA:
I tried IExpress, and I'm running into this error:
[image: ARGH]

(Picture uploaded but for some reason, neither picture in this post is showing)

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in <module>
    code = importer.get_code(moduleName)
ZipImportError: can't find module 'projec~1__main__'
```

Comment: cx_Freeze does not have a way to make single file exes, but you could use [IExpress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress) to make a self-extracting archive that runs your exe after extraction.

Answer (score 0):

I did NOT find a way to do exactly what I wanted. I did, however, discover that I was getting an installer I wasn't aware of for distribution that did install everything that was in my exe directory.

File path was ~\dist, and it contained only an .msi file. Launching it installed everything that was in ~\build\exe.win32-2.7

Comment: You probably ran `python setup.py bdist_msi` at some point - that's what makes the .msi installer.